# Tkinter: How to move widgets on canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, widget, move

Im tryin to do a simply app that move every widget on canvas. First step i moved a rectangle, but now i want to move a widget! I thought "it would be the same thing!" but im wrong :(
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

clicked = False

def callback(event):
    global clicked, start, pre_x,pre_y

    if clicked:
        clicked = False

    else:
        if event.x >= canvas.coords(rec)[0] and event.x <= canvas.coords(rec)[2] and event.y >= canvas.coords(rec)[1] and event.y <=canvas.coords(rec)[3]:
            clicked = True
            canvas.itemconfig(rec,fill = "blue")
            pre_x = event.x
            pre_y = event.y
            canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>",movement)

def movement(event):
    global clicked, start, pre_x,pre_y

    if clicked:
        x_diff = event.x - pre_x
        y_diff = event.y - pre_y
        #print("RecCoord[1]=" + str(canvas.coords(rec)[1]))
        pre_x = event.x
        pre_y = event.y
        #print("RecCoord[1] = " + str(canvas.coords(rec)[1]))
        canvas.move(rec,x_diff,y_diff)

window = Tk()
w = window.winfo_screenwidth()
h = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (w, h))
window.title('Finestra di disegno')
canvas = Canvas(window, width = w, height = h)
rec = canvas.create_rectangle(100,100, 100 + 55,100 + 26)
canvas.pack()
tmpbutton = Button(window, text = "Click me!")
tmpbutton.pack()
tmpbutton.update()

canvas.create_window(100,100, window = tmpbutton, anchor = NW, tags = 'button')
canvas.bind("<Button-1>",callback)
tmpbutton.bind("<Button-1>",callback)
window.mainloop()
```

My idea was to create a rectangle under the button widget, so when i move the rectangle i can refresh the button coords with the new coords of the rectangle! But the canvas don't capture the event on widget, because every widget have an event handler, right? So i bind the button widget too, but without result!!
Can someone help me?? I repeat my question, i need to move a widget on canvas as i do with the rectangle... Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Movement is simply an illusion. You draw at one place, clear, draw at another place.

Comment: Uhmmmm... i see... but can you show me an example please?? :D

Comment: If you need `tkinter` I'd rather not. Can I show you Pygame?

Comment: Pygame? What are you talking about?

Comment: If this pygame can help me to resolve my question, you can show me all :D

Comment: See [here](http://repl.it/uh3/1) for a demo. You need to install Pygame locally to run the program.

Comment: I've installed pygame and i ve copied the include in the include folder of my python interpreter, and the entire folder lib copied in the folder Lib of my python interpreter, but i ve this error!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygame.locals

Comment: Note, i ve python 3.4 its this the problem?

Comment: Are you running it on your computer? I simply shared it online, you're not supposed to run it there.

Comment: this is now the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chaw359/PycharmProjects/testPygame/testPygame.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pygame.locals import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
I controlled in my folder, and its true! I don t have base.py module, i tryied to download other and other version but this module miss everywhere... can you pass me that module?

Comment: Please share your screen using [this](http://bit.ly/1LR6wPT) so I can set things up for you.

Comment: I think that i ve to share you this ? https://join.me/323-781-533